# How to stop a nodejs command line script

Tags: mysql, node.js

I had to write a nodejs cli script to fetch over 1M records from mysql is done, those records had paths to tiff images which I needed to convert to pdf and then split those pdfs into single page pdfs, and finally insert and update records in mysql.

To fetch the data from mysql I used the following code

```
conn.query(myQueryToGet1MRecords)
  .stream()
  .pipe(stream.Transform({
    objectMode: true,
    transform: function(data, encoding, callback){
      doWhatINeedToDo(data);
      callback();
    }
  }));
```

The function 'doWhatINeedToDo' does the work calling a series of callbacks until the final update to mysql. Anyway given that each call to 'doWhatINeedToDo' is asynchronous, I don't know how to finish the process execution, I mean I don't know where to put `process.exit()`

How do I know when node has finished all the work to safely exit the process without affecting ongoing processes?

Comment: keep `process.exit()` after callback.

Comment: I did that, but then the process finishes after the execution of the first record killing all the other ongoing processes